# boto3 python package installed but aws/config does not exist

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I installed AWS CLI and Boto3 but can't find Shared Credentials File to put user access key.
I tried to install it on Windows 7 and Ubuntu and I have got the same issue, simply can't find the Shared Credentials File in the default location `~/.aws/credentials`

I was using this official guide of [boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can create your ~/.aws folder yourself then manually key in and save the config into ~/.aws/credentials and ~/.aws/config

If you think it is troublesome, after you install awscli usign apt , you can  run [aws configure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html)  to use the shell interface to create those folder.

```
sudo apt install awscli

aws configure
```

The aws shell script will ask you for access key and create ~/.aws/credential and ~/.aws/config